# accessing an image component in flex from actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an image component in flex (mxml file), like below

```
<mx:image id="imageID"/>
```

I have a separate actionscript class and I am trying to set the source of the image from the init() in the actionscript class.

I am trying to access it like,

```
    [Embed(source="hello_world.png")]
        [Bindable]
        public var hello_world:Class;

        init()
    {
.................

        imageID.source = new hello_world();
....................
    }
```

But the image doesnt get displayed.

So my question is, how do we access the image component declared in the mxml page in the actionscript class.

Comment: ...and?  You forgot to ask a question here.

Comment: I apologize for overlooking. Thanks for pointing it out @Brian

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the answers on [AS3 Embed images class and then get these images into another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549136/as3-embed-images-class-and-then-get-these-images-into-another-class), you just need to cast your `hello_world` class as a `Bitmap`:

```
init()
{
.................

    imageID.source = new hello_world() as Bitmap;
....................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

imageID.source = hello_world;